# How to Store call back function name inside javascript object and call

Tags: javascript, callback

i am trying to build this function data get an JavaScript object and process that some time it's need a call back function so i am trying pass that function inside the object but when i call this it's says function dosen't exist and yet still this function exist and when i pass this as parameter it's working this only happen when i get callback function name from JavaScript Object

```
function Ajax(data){
   //ajax stuff
   var filtered_respons  = response_from_ajax;
     //tryed this all not working
            data['callback'](filtered_response,'loading');
            var fun_name = data['callback'];
            fun_name(filtered_response,'loading');//



 }
```

---

### Updated

and from html page i am calling this function as this

```
   let data = {
    url:'./assets/php/category.php',
    type:'POST',
    callback :'toprender',
    data:{all_cats:1},
    element_name:'cat'
  }
  Ajax(data);
```

And when i try this way it's working

```
AjaxCaller(data,topfunction,true);
```

**This is the whole function**

```
    AjaxCaller(data,callback,need){
     var loader= "";
     if(typeof data['loader'] !== "undefined"){
        loader = $("#"+data['loader']);
     }else{
        loader = $("#loading"); 
     }
     loader.show();
if(typeof data['url'] !== "undefined" && typeof data['type'] !== "undefined"){
    var $self = this;
    $.ajax({
        url:data['url'],
        type:data['type'],
        data:data['data'],
        success:function(response){
            loader.hide();
            var response = JSON.parse(response);
            var filtered_response = $self.ajaxError(response);
            if(need==true){
               callback(filtered_response,data['element_name']);                

            }

        }


    });




}else{
    console.log('Please Re Check The Objects');
}

 }
```

Comment: What doesn't exist? What is the function that supposedly exists? What parameter are you passing when it works? How are you getting the callback function name from a JS object?

Comment: How are you calling `Ajax`? What are you passing in?

Comment: i have updated my question @T.J.Crowder now it's has when it's working and not working.

Comment: @vlaz  i think all other answer are there in the code for getting call function name from JS object  `data['callback'](para1,param2)`

Comment: @ThalindaBandara *"And when i try this way it's working"* I'm confused. if it works that way, why are you trying to do it the other way?

Comment: Thank you guys problem solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to use a **string** as a function. You can't do that.

You probably just want to change `callback :'toprender'` to `callback :toprender`:

```
let data = {
  url:'./assets/php/category.php',
  type:'POST',
  callback :toprender,
  data:{all_cats:1},
  element_name:'cat'
}
Ajax(data);
```

That sets `callback` to the fucntion, rather than a string.

Live Example:

```js
function toprender() {
  console.log("toprender called");
}

function Ajax(data) {
  data.callback();
}

let data = {
  url:'./assets/php/category.php',
  type:'POST',
  callback :toprender,
  data:{all_cats:1},
  element_name:'cat'
}
Ajax(data);
```